# need to redirect url without using the function header

Tags: php, redirect

I need to redirect my page to another, but I can't use the `header` function, is there any other way to do it?

What a I need to do is something like this:

```
if (test){
   ---do something---
   redirect
} else {
   return false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you cannot redirect via header function, that means you have some bad logic and wanna redirect when your content is already outputed. You should change your logic, or use easy method with html/meta/js redirect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if (test){
   ---do something---
   die("<script>location.href = 'http://www.google.com'</script>");
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A meta-redirect

```
    if (test){
       //do something
       echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=yourpage.php">';//This causes the browser to open the new page after 0 seconds, i.e immediately.
    }  else {
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: with this, theres no problem with there having output before?

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: While this is a valid method for initiating a page redirect, it is important to note that meta tags are intended for the head of the document. I'd suggest that the OPs inability to use the header function may suggest this method as being not well suited. However more info is required to be sure.

Comment: That's perfect! After restful calls (REST) I've to redirect the user and that solution is the perfect alternative to header('Location...');!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (test){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function () { top.location.href = '" . $url . "/page.php#contact'; };
</script>";
} else {
   return false
}
```

Comment: ended up using window.location.href

Answer (score 1):

```
if (test){
   ---do something---
  $URL="http://yourwebsite.com/";
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
} else {
   return false;
}
```

If you're wondering that why I have used both **Meta tag and JavaScript to Redirect**, then the answer is very simple.

If JavaScript is Disabled in the Browser, then meta tag will redirect the page.